# Technique to use preview API's

Tags: github3.py

I often find I want to use preview APIs that GitHub offers. Is there a recommended way to add those APIs to minimize hassles when they become supported? (e.g. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/invitations/)

My current approach is to hack local changes - there must be a better way!

Plus points if the way to add can be on-the-path to a pull request.

Comment: Hi Hal! It seems you're asking about contributing to github3.py's development? That's perfectly suitable for the issue tracker. We regularly add preview APIs before they're completely stable, but I and the other maintainers don't have the time to keep up with GitHub's API. So, other folks have been contributing these changes and we've been incorporating them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about development practices of a library, not looking for help with code.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 I don't quite agree with closing, as this is about help with the code -- how to get the appropriate version of it, as it was unclear to me from the repo docs what to use, and the CONTRIBUTING file specifically says to not ask questions in issues. :) I think your first comment would be a fine answer for folks like me to find in the future.